# Gdal_rasterize nodata_value does not work

Tags: python, python-3.4, gdal, rasterizing

I want to rasterize a source layer made of polygons. No matter what value I assign to "NoData_value", the outcome in my array is always = 0. 
I am using python 3.4. 
Can anyone help me understand please ?

```
source_srs = source_layer.GetSpatialRef()
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()

# parameters of output file
xSize = math.ceil((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)  # number of pixels in the x direction given pixel_size, rounded up to the nearest pixel
ySize = math.ceil((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)  # number of pixels in the y direction given pixel_size, rounded up to the nearest pixel
x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / xSize)  # size of pixel in meters rounded to fit bbox
y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / ySize)  # size of pixel in meters rounded to fit bbox

NoData_value = -9999

# Create output dataset as memory
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', xSize, ySize, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, x_res, 0, y_max, 0, -y_res))
wkt_projection = source_srs.ExportToWkt()
target_ds.SetProjection(wkt_projection)

band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)

# rasterize
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, options=["ATTRIBUTE=expo" ])

# Read as numpy array
array = band.ReadAsArray()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want the values outside the polygons to have *NoData_value*?

Then, add

```
band.Fill(NoData_value)
```

before calling *gdal.RasterizeLayer*. You need this because *gdal.RasterizeLayer* only modifies (burn) the values inside the polygons.

You will need to change the format *gdal.GDT_Byte* to a format that can handle -9999 such as for example *GDT_Float32*:

```
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', int(xSize), int(ySize), 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
```

**Note** : data type is the 5th argument, not the 4th as in your code. The 4th argument should be used for the number of bands:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180708154005/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALDriver.html#adb7bff9007fa5190d6cf742cf76942a8)

I tested and it works on my size.